# Setting specific bin length in python list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a straightforward question but I'm facing issues for conversion.

I have a pandas dataframe column which I converted to a list. It has both positive and negative values:

bin_length = 5

list = [-200, -112, -115, 0, 50, 120, 250]

I need to group these numbers into a bin of length 5.

For example:

-100 to -95 should have a value of -100

-95 to -90 should have a value of -95

Similarly for positive values:

0 to 5 should be 5

5 to 10 should be 10

What I have tried until now:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe['rd2'].values.tolist(), columns = ['values'])
bins = np.arange(0, df['values'].max() + 5, 5)
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['values'], bins, include_lowest = True)
```

But this doesn't account for negative values and then I get problems in converting the pandas interval into a separate columns for list.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Why your range starts from 0 instead of `bins = np.arange(df["values"].min(), df['values'].max() + 5, 5)`?

Comment: Fixed that. How do I convert the intervals to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the correct lower limit with `np.arange`:

```
bins = np.arange(df["values"].min(), df['values'].max() + 5, 5)
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['values'], bins, include_lowest = True)

print (df)

   values                bins
0    -200  (-200.001, -195.0]
1    -112    (-115.0, -110.0]
2    -115    (-120.0, -115.0]
3       0         (-5.0, 0.0]
4      50        (45.0, 50.0]
5     120      (115.0, 120.0]
6     250      (245.0, 250.0]
```

Convert the intervals back to a list:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex(df["bins"])

print ([[x,y] for x,y in zip(s.left, s.right)])

[[-200.001, -195.0], [-115.0, -110.0], [-120.0, -115.0], [-5.0, 0.0], [45.0, 50.0], [115.0, 120.0], [245.0, 250.0]]
```